# Azure File Storage Offline

Tags: file-sharing, iis, azure, asp.net

If one was to use Azure File Storage via SMB (net user mounting) is it correct to assume that it can also be configured for offline caching (should network connectivity fail).

The reason being is, i'm keen to see how one can make IIS point to a Cloud-shared directory to help with legacy ASP.NET deployment strategy. My concern is that should network drop out, IIS can still continue to serve internal websites.